# ffmpeg slow down video and audio leads to garbled audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i test-video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=(2/1)*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=.5[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" slow-output.mp4
```

And the audio that comes out is very "digital" and garbled. If I do the same slowing down manually through iMovie or FinalCut, the audio changes, but doesn't have this digital, garbled feel. Anything I can do to mitigate this?

Comment: Not sure.. the `setpts` filter to slow down is more of a hack anyway, since it just squishes everything or spreads out the samples. Programs such as FinalCut or iMovie will probably apply some interpolation to smooth out the signal.

Comment: @slhck But that should affect only the video, not the audio, right? It's the atempo filter that messes with the audio. The video actually comes out really nicely (since video was taken at 60fps anyway). It's the audio that just sounds terrible.

Comment: Perhaps `sox` will provide an adequate output, then use `ffmpeg` to deal with the video and finally mux both outputs.